# Data structure with user specified order

Tags: c#, list, sql-order-by

I have this class :

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I want to store instances of `Item` in a list, and keep it ordered like the user has ordered them (Likely to be in a GUI with up-down arrows while selecting an Item)...

Should I be adding an order member to my `Item` class, or is there a specific datastructure that can keep an arbitrary user-specified order.

Note: I'm going to use this to keep a list of items, in the order a person has seen them, walking in a store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to persist the list to a database then you may want to include an Order property in your Item class; databases such as SQL Server do not guarantee the order of the result set.

Answer (score 1):

List/Array/Collection are names for ordered sequence of items.

`List<Item>` is enough to keep items in particular order. Note that re-ordering items will be "slow" ( O(n) ) operation in this case to move single item in new place. If you just need Add regular `List<T>` is probably the easiest choice that does not require any additional fields.